# Some letters are missing in the terminal. Why?

Tags: command-line, fonts

When the file path is displayed certain letters (like 'F') are missing in the path in terminal. It was corrected when the `Use system fixed width font` was unchecked in the profile preferences. Why does this happen?

Comment: Would you add a screenshot, so that we can get an idea about what you are experiencing? Also is it just 'F' or any other chars? How about 'M' and 'I'?

Comment: Also which font do you use now? Add these information to the question.

Comment: And finally, install `gnome-tweak-tool`, and in it's Fonts section, tell me what the current system-wide monospace font is.

Comment: I cant post the screenshot. I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: The font is Ubuntu Mono.

Answer (score 2):

Are you are using truetype fonts when the terminal is expecting monospaced?

Here are some thoughts that need be considered so as to understand why this is the case, please forgive me if this is common knowledge to you but it springs to my mind in response to your query.

Most consoles today are simulations: Back in the days when terminals were the interface with main frame computers, the graphical output was far less of a concern than it is today, there was simply neither the power nor the inclination for fancy fonts. [Typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) had not yet come into consideration. Above anything else, computing resources were far to sparse to implement such graphical niceties.

The structure of the console is essentially a matrix; a grid of rows and columns that are compiled in buffers; think perhaps of shelves with compartments all of the same size so that all of the shelves always have the same length.

Now for this to function when each letter fills a single box on a shelf or in a grid; the individual characters must be of equal width; If they are any wider than the box they will either not be displayed at all, or, they will be displayed incorrectly; This is why a terminal needs "[monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)" fonts.

You might think of it this way; the terminal is fundamentally structured by the fonts themselves, they are its building blocks. When you change the font the terminal size also changes.

In more powerful machines we find a bitmap outputs or vector, in which pixels or and coordinates are the constructors essentially replacing the font as the basic element with dots. When this is the case; fonts with different widths can be used.